# Reading/browsing tree files generated by windows

Tags: data-visualization

I'm looking for a software that allows me to read/browse a tree file generated by windows cmd like

```
tree /f /a > tree.txt
```

Is there something like that?

Comment: Eyeballs? What exactly are you asking here? And why are you so grumpy?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same with PowerShell, try this command

```
Get-ChildItem | tree c:\your_path /f | Export-Clixml your_filename.xml
```

Then you can use any program to read the XML, also you can use the export to CSV with the param *Export-Csv* instead of *Export-Clixml*.

Comment: Here is [the syntax](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176841.aspx) for _Get-ChildItem_

Comment: Any way to convert already created tree.txt? And which xml browser is recommended?

Comment: @Josem you ought to consider posting an answer